# Apply python lazy map for in-place functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-evaluation, map-function

Sometimes, I build up a thing by repeatedly applying map, and then having python perform the operations all at once.

For example, I could build up a list of lists of ranges like so:

```
foo = [256]*3
foo = map(range, foo)
foo = map(list, foo)
```

So far, all I have is a single list of 3 items, and a couple of map objects.  Laziness achieved.  If, at this point, I would like to evaluate `foo`, I could call, e.g., `list(foo)` and all of the `map`s would execute and I would get a nested list of ranges.

However, suppose that I would like to map a function over `foo` that operates in place.

```
foo = [256]*3
foo = map(range, foo)
foo = map(list, foo)
in_place_op = map(lambda x: x.sort(reverse=True), foo)
```

If I try to evaluate `in_place_op`, it fails to apply correctly over the elements of `foo`.  This happens even if I go ahead and evaluate `foo`, since `in_place_op` is applied to the map `foo` used to point at:

```
foo = [256]*3
foo = map(range, foo)
foo = map(list, foo)
in_place_op = map(lambda x: x.sort(reverse=True), foo)
foo = list(foo)
list(in_place_op)
print(foo)
#[[1,2,3...],[1,2,3...],[1,2,3...]]
#expected [[255,254,...],...]
```

In order to get this to work, I have to `list(foo)` **before** `map`ing `in_place_op` over `foo`.  However, this defeats all the laziness I was building into the thing.

How do I correctly `map` an in-place function in python to maintain the lazy evaluation property?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `print(foo)` prints a list of lists, but `print(list(in_place_op))` indeed outputs an empty list.

Comment: You can `tee` the iterator if multiple consumers need to use it, but then you can end up storing the whole thing in memory anyway.

Comment: @ForceBru, you are correct.

Comment: What's stopping you from mapping `list` lazily?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi nothing.  It's the sort operation that doesn't map lazily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple `or` evaluation trick:

(for those in-place functions that return `None` - the `or` condition is a way to go in your case)

```
foo = [256]*3
foo = map(range, foo)
foo = map(list, foo)
in_place_op = map(lambda x: x.sort(reverse=True) or x, foo)
print(list(in_place_op))
```

The output:

```
[[255, 254, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 243, 242, 241, 240, 239, 238, 237, 236, 235, 234, 233, 232, 231, 230, 229, 228, 227, 226, 225, 224, 223, 222, 221, 220, 219, 218, 217, 216, 215, 214, 213, 212, 211, 210, 209, 208, 207, 206, 205, 204, 203, 202, 201, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 189, 188, 187, 186, 185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 177, 176, 175, 174, 173, 172, 171, 170, 169, 168, 167, 166, 165, 164, 163, 162, 161, 160, 159, 158, 157, 156, 155, 154, 153, 152, 151, 150, 149, 148, 147, 146, 145, 144, 143, 142, 141, 140, 139, 138, 137, 136, 135, 134, 133, 132, 131, 130, 129, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 123, 122, 121, 120, 119, 118, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [255, 254, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 243, 242, 241, 240, 239, 238, 237, 236, 235, 234, 233, 232, 231, 230, 229, 228, 227, 226, 225, 224, 223, 222, 221, 220, 219, 218, 217, 216, 215, 214, 213, 212, 211, 210, 209, 208, 207, 206, 205, 204, 203, 202, 201, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 189, 188, 187, 186, 185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 177, 176, 175, 174, 173, 172, 171, 170, 169, 168, 167, 166, 165, 164, 163, 162, 161, 160, 159, 158, 157, 156, 155, 154, 153, 152, 151, 150, 149, 148, 147, 146, 145, 144, 143, 142, 141, 140, 139, 138, 137, 136, 135, 134, 133, 132, 131, 130, 129, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 123, 122, 121, 120, 119, 118, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [255, 254, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 243, 242, 241, 240, 239, 238, 237, 236, 235, 234, 233, 232, 231, 230, 229, 228, 227, 226, 225, 224, 223, 222, 221, 220, 219, 218, 217, 216, 215, 214, 213, 212, 211, 210, 209, 208, 207, 206, 205, 204, 203, 202, 201, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 189, 188, 187, 186, 185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 177, 176, 175, 174, 173, 172, 171, 170, 169, 168, 167, 166, 165, 164, 163, 162, 161, 160, 159, 158, 157, 156, 155, 154, 153, 152, 151, 150, 149, 148, 147, 146, 145, 144, 143, 142, 141, 140, 139, 138, 137, 136, 135, 134, 133, 132, 131, 130, 129, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 123, 122, 121, 120, 119, 118, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
```

---

Another `in-place` example:

```
in_place_op = map(lambda x: x.insert(0, 1000) or x, foo)
print(list(in_place_op))
```

The output:

```
[[1000, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255], [1000, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255], [1000, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255]]
```

---

***Bonus*** trick for *in-place* functions that return some value like `dict.pop(key[, default])` (if `key` is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return *default*.)

Let's say we have 10 dictionaries mapped in lazy manner and the final list should contain all dictionaries with a particular key removed (ex. `a` key):

```
foo = [['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz', range(26)]] * 10
foo = map(lambda s: zip(*s), foo)
foo = map(dict, foo)
in_place_op = map(lambda d: d if d.pop('a') else d, foo)
print(list(in_place_op))
```

The output:

```
[{'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11, 'm': 12, 'n': 13, 'o': 14, 'p': 15, 'q': 16, 'r': 17, 's': 18, 't': 19, 'u': 20, 'w': 21, 'x': 22, 'y': 23, 'z': 24}]
```